# Internet Explorer object doesn't have Document child

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get my hands on filling in a form with PowerShell. So I am simply trying to do this:

```
$ieObject = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application';
$ieObject.Visible = $true;;
$ieObject.Navigate('https://www.randomizer.org/');
$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document;
$inputbox = $currentDocument.getElementByID('randSets');
$inputbox.value = "My Value";
```

However this gives me the error

> ```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
> At line:5 char:1
> + $inputbox = $currentDocument.getElementByID("randSets");
> ```

I don't exactly know why but my ieObject doesn't have all the properties (I only have 9 when I'm supposed to have around 50)and methods it should have. When I use `Get-Member` I can't see `Document` in there so is it normal or am I doing something really wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\n> $ieObject | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.__ComObject

Name                      MemberType Definition                                            
----                      ---------- ----------                                            
CreateObjRef              Method     System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(type re...
Equals                    Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                        
GetHashCode               Method     int GetHashCode()                                     
GetLifetimeService        Method     System.Object GetLifetimeService()                    
GetType                   Method     type GetType()                                        
InitializeLifetimeService Method     System.Object InitializeLifetimeService()             
ToString                  Method     string ToString()
```

Thank you in advance!

---

I am using:

- Windows 10 Enterprise (so I'm thinking maybe my company blocked some features, I will check with my IT department)
- Powershell version is 5.1
- Internet explorer version 11.885

---

**EDIT:** as suggested in the comment I tried to use VBA to do the same thing as my powershell script and I got the same error on the `Document` object `Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed'`. This means I can't access properly my Internet Explorer application. In this case I think I should wait for the final answer of my IT department and then add more to this.

So I have access to the object and every property of it until I use Navigate. Then I get errors even for `Get-Member` like:

> ```
> Get-Member : The following exception occurred while retrieving the string representation 
> for property "Application" : "The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 
> 0x800706BA)"
> ```

Comment: I've seen this behavior with IE a number of times but haven't been able to replicate it across devices.  If you need an automation engine, I would not recommend using the IE COM object at all but instead opt for something like [tag:selenium] instead.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thanks, I will take a look at that

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Selenium seems interesting however I would prefer something that I don't have to install so that's why I chose PowerShell in the first place. Thank you for the tip though!

Comment: Using modules should not be frowned upon as it's a normal part of the software development process.  You could always bundle the Selenium dll with your script for use.

Comment: @JackA Not sure why you down voted both answers. The answers clearly address the `null` exception that you are receiving. If you are having additional issues, please update the post.

Comment: @jrider Please don't assume you know who downvoted. OP probably didn't.

Comment: @JackA, I try to test your code and it produced the same error. Further I test the code suggested by jrider and find that his code is working fine and adding the value in the textbox. So I suggest you to again make a test with his code to see if it works or not. If still issue persist than try to inform us which version of OS and which version of IE you are using for making this test? If you are using any older version than it is recommended to upgrade to IE 11 version.

Comment: @jrider as Modus said I didn't down vote anything... I will update the post with my versions & OS

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Still not working for me. I will add additional information about my setup in the original post.

Comment: I seen the previous comments that you don't want to install anything to do this automation. Is there any possibility for you to use VBA? If you are available with that option than we can try to provide a code a sample VBA code that you can try to use to solve the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT mh yeah I can definitely use VBA

Comment: Please try to refer this example of VBA. https://textuploader.com/11u1w It is working fine on my side. See here: https://i.postimg.cc/vZkgc618/70.gif Let me know about your testing result. If it works for you than I will post it as an answer.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT It doesn't work but it's interesting because the error is the same. I get a `Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed'`. So I think I should wait for the final answer of my IT department

Comment: Does it open the IE? On which line you got that error?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes both on PowerShell and VBA the browser opens and navigates to the right web page. And I always get the error when I try to access the `Document` object.

Comment: Please try this code. https://textuploader.com/11ut6 Helpful article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/ let me know about the results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT hey thank you again for your help! The solution to my problem was actually fairly simple as I just needed to run my script as administrator (on powershell and vba).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was actually very simple, so simple I didn't think about it... I have to **run the programs as administrator** and then it works.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What looks like is happening is the page has not loaded by the time you are calling `$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document;` causing `$currentDocument` to be `$null`.

You should be able to fix it by using `.Busy`

```
$ieObject = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ieObject.Visible = $true
$ieObject.Navigate('https://www.randomizer.org/');
do{
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
}while($ieObject.Busy)
$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document
$inputbox = $currentDocument.getElementByID('randSets')
```

Comment: @JackA when I ran this, I was able to access `$inputbox` variable.

Comment: I will try to restart everything and see if the problem gets solved. And as mentioned in the edit of the original post I will ask my IT department.

Answer (score 0):

This is working here:

```
$ieObject = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application

$ieObject.Visible = $true
[void]$ieObject.Navigate2('https://www.randomizer.org/')

while ($ieObject.busy) {
        sleep -seconds 1
}

$currentDocument = $ieObject.Document
$inputbox = $currentDocument.getElementByID('randSets')
$inputbox.value = "My Value"
```

You have to wait till the browser has loaded all objects.